# Android action bar icon id

Tags: android, icons

I have an icon in the action bar that I need to change on click. If icon A is showing, it needs to be changed to icon B and vice versa. The problem with this scenario is that I can not find a method which returns the current icon id. I have no way to check which icon is currently showing. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: That linked article shows how to change the app icon.  Did you need to change the app icon or a menu action icon?